# scala: classOf[], exceptions and :: operator for lists weird behavior

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, type-inference

I have encountered some realy weird behavior in scala.
i wrote a generic method that takes as an argument an error prone code, and a list of "valid exceptions", and it should execute the code, while retrying the code when a "valid exception" is thrown.

the method works great and i use it in several places.
but then, one of the method calls failed at compilation. 
and the cause was the initialization of the list of exceptions.

i have tried it in the REPL, to make sure there is no other cause, and you can see the results for yourself:

```
me@my-lap:~$ scala -cp /path/to/maven/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/path/to/maven/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/path/to/maven/repository/me/my-utils/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-utils-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/path/to/maven/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.jar
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.apache.http.conn.{HttpHostConnectException,ConnectTimeoutException}
import org.apache.http.conn.{HttpHostConnectException, ConnectTimeoutException}

scala> import me.util.exceptions.RetryException
import me.util.exceptions.RetryException

scala> val validEx = classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: classOf[RetryException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil
<console>:9: error: inferred type arguments [java.lang.Class[_ >: _1 with org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException <: java.lang.Exception]] do not conform to method ::'s type parameter bounds [B >: java.lang.Class[_ >: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with me.util.exceptions.RetryException <: java.lang.Exception]]
       val validEx = classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: classOf[RetryException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil
                                                      ^
```

when initializing a list from all 3 exception types, the code fails with this weird error.
so i tried to initialize with every subset of 2 exceptions from those 3:

```
scala> val validEx = classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: classOf[RetryException] :: Nil
validEx: List[java.lang.Class[_ >: me.util.exceptions.RetryException with org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException <: java.lang.Exception]] = List(class org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException, class me.util.exceptions.RetryException)

scala> val validEx = classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil
validEx: List[java.lang.Class[_ >: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException <: java.io.IOException]] = List(class org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException, class org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException)

scala> val validEx = classOf[RetryException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil
validEx: List[java.lang.Class[_ >: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with me.util.exceptions.RetryException <: java.lang.Exception]] = List(class me.util.exceptions.RetryException, class org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException)
```

and it worked! i also tried to crete the list of all 3 exception types with `List()` instead of using `::` operator. and it also worked:

```
scala> val validEx = List(classOf[ConnectTimeoutException], classOf[RetryException], classOf[HttpHostConnectException])
validEx: List[java.lang.Class[_ >: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with me.util.exceptions.RetryException with org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException <: java.lang.Exception]] = List(class org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException, class me.util.exceptions.RetryException, class org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException)
```

BTW, the implementation of `RetryException` is:

```
class RetryException extends Exception {}
```

So why did it happened? is it a bug with scala's `::` operator?
and why couldn't the compiler infer a better type than: `List[java.lang.Class[_ >: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with me.util.exceptions.RetryException with org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException <: java.lang.Exception]]`
(my method excepts an argument of type: `validExceptions: List[Class[_ <: java.lang.Throwable]]` which is a much more concise type. i would except the compiler to figure out somethong like: `List[Class[_ <: java.lang.Exception]]`

(i'm running on ubuntu 12.04 64bit with Scala version 2.9.2 (Java7 oracle 1.7.0_17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply looks like an inference problem.

Try to replace `Nil` with `List.empty[Exception]`:

```
val validEx = classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: classOf[RetryException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: List.empty[Class[_ <: Exception]]
```

This should fix it.

Now let's see what happens in the original code:

```
val validEx = classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: classOf[RetryException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil
```

This is evaluated from right to left, because `::` is right-associative.

---

So first, the compiler evaluates `classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil`. The inferred type is `List[Class[HttpHostConnectException]]`.
Let's call the result of this expression `tmp1: List[Class[HttpHostConnectException]]`

---

Then the compiler evaluates `classOf[RetryException] :: tmp1`. Type inference tries to unify the types on the left and on the right, and comes up with `List[_ >: RetryException with HttpHostConnectException]`.
You might wonder why it does not infer `List[Class[Exception]]`. This is because `Class` is not covariant (it is invariant), so `Class[HttpHostConnectException]` and `Class[RetryException]` are not subtypes of `Class[Exception]`.
Now you might also argue the compiler could have inferred the simpler (but less precise) type `List[AnyRef]`. But the compiler just tries to be as precise as possible, which is obviously pretty usefulll in general. But in this case it will pose a problem with the next step.
So let's call the result of this expression `tmp2: List[_ >: RetryException with HttpHostConnectException]` and see what happens next.

---

Finally the compiler evaluates `classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: tmp2`.

Here the signature of `::` mandates that `classOf[ConnectTimeoutException]` be a subtype of `RetryException with HttpHostConnectException` (the type of the list's elements so far). In other words `ConnectTimeoutException` is required to extends both `RetryException` and `HttpHostConnectException`, which clearly is not the case, and thus you get a compile error

Comment: thanks. this is a very good answer. but i'm wondering, when i switched `Nil` to `List.empty[Exception]`, the infered type was: `List[java.io.Serializable]` shouldn't it be better to put: `List.empty[Class[_ <: Exception]]` instead? then, the infered type will be as concise as it can...

Comment: Oops, yes of course. I did not intend to say `List.empty[Exception]` in the first place, but `List.empty[Class[Exception]]`. Given that `Class` is invariant, this would actually not compile and indeed you need to use `List.empty[Class[_ <: Exception]]`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling the cons operator (`::`) multiple times, the type inferencer tries to evaluate the correct type parameter of the `List` for you at each step.

After the first couple of cons opearation

```
classOf[RetryException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil
```

the inferenced type is not compatible with the third cons call.
The error message tells you that the above value has the inferenced type (for the list elements) of

```
java.lang.Class[_ >: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with me.util.exceptions.RetryException <: java.lang.Exception]
```

So it expects that additional prepended elements must be supertypes of the above.

You can verify this on the console by doing

```
val intermediateList = classOf[RetryException] :: classOf[HttpHostConnectException] :: Nil
```

And look at the result type, and then try to prepend

```
classOf[ConnectTimeoutException] :: intermediateList
```

To get the same error as in the OP

---

As @Régis Jean-Gilles suggested, if you create the `List` specifying that the first element you build upon is of your expected type

```
List.empty[Exception]
```

The compiler should have no problem.

The same happens when you use the `List(..., ...)` object factory, since type inference for a method call is performed one parameter list (set of parens) at a time.
This means that the compiler uses all the arguments to define the correct `List` type

Comment: thanks. i now understand why the infered type was the (some might say ugly) expression: `List[java.lang.Class[_ >: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with me.util.exceptions.RetryException with org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException <: java.lang.Exception]]`

Comment: ugly may be, but it's just the minimum needed to satisfy the call constraint without you manually doing it... I'd call it powerful, until you need to inspect it... =D